# Turn Page Numbers into helvet, abbreviations & left flush TOC

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, acronyms

Maybe someone can help me with these:

I have three things I'm trying to finish off for my thesis with the formatting.

The first is the page numbering - I've been asked to use arial (helvet in my case) but I notice that while the entire document changes to the new format with no problem, the page numbers stay as the original LaTeX format. Would anyone have a suggestion of how to get these into ?

The second is to do with the list of abbreviations. I just can't get it to work. I've tried the nomencl package, the glossary package and the acronym package. In fairness, I got the acronym package to work but it's not ideal as it doesn't put them in alphabetical order. Also, it doesn't suit the format I have for the list of figures/tables.

The nomencl package seems to be what I need/give the results I want but in all the examples I read they say something like "makeindex file.glo -s nomencl.ist -o file.gls" or something to that extent. I use TeXworks so I have the option to make the index separately but I get an error that "Can't find Thesis Report Gl.idx". To be honest I'm totally lost with it.

Thirdly, the format I have to use requires that the TOC is left justified with the chapter headings bold and the sub-headings as standard with no indent. So far I've not been able to find a way around that. Any examples online just don't suit.

I'll give an idea of what the preamble is so far:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage [top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.0cm,right=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{187,187,187} %For titlepage
\definecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{220,220,220} %For titlepage
\definecolor{lightgreen}{RGB}{96,176,80} %For titlepage
\usepackage{textpos} %Image position on title page

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{hyperref} % makes things clickable
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[square]{natbib} %"square" gives square brackets around the citation
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\lhead{Capacity Analysis of}
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{IEV.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}


\begin{document}


\input{./title.tex}
```

In the main body there's nothing too unusual. Tables, figures, equations, a few tikzpictures, citations. The usual basically.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Turning your code snippet into a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem will make it much easier for us to reproduce your situation.

Comment: Regarding `nomencl`: why don't you run `makeindex` from the command line? That should work in any case.

Answer (score 2):

To turn the page numbers to 9pt Helvetica, centered at the bottom, put

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont\thepage}
```

in your preamble.

To use the `nomencl` package, put a

```
\makenomenclature
```

into your preamble, this should give you the desired GI.idx file once you TeXed your document, and you can proceed by calling `makeindex` on it, just as you described. I also used the package `glossaries`, which can handle multiple glossaries.

For changing the appearance of the ToC, I recommend the `tocloft` package. To make chapter titles bold, you can then issue

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
```

To change the indention of the section titles, do

```
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}
```

More details are in the documentation of `tocloft`.

Comment: There's no `\makeindex` needed. The `\makenomenclature`  mentioned in the manual should suffice.